# Drawing text to the screen with slick util

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm making a QOL modification for a really old LWJGL game, and I'm attempting to draw ttf text to the screen. From what I can tell, slick-util is easiest way to do this.

What I have done is created the TrueTypeFont instance with this:

`Font awtFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24); font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);`

but it does not work, it looks like this when I draw it to the screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ior2Y.jpg

I tried a couple of things that I found on the internet, such as enabling blend, and setting the draw buffer to the back setting. None of these have had any affect on what is being rendered to the screen.

Any ideas of why this isn't working would be much appreciated!

Comment: What language have you used? As far as I know, Slick doesn't support languages other than English, so unsupported characters will disappear

Comment: Yes, I was using English